# error while opening a MS Project file on SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, ms-project

I am trying to open the MS Project file saved in .MPP format, using MS Project 2013, when ever i try to open the file, it asks me to login and throws the below error.

[image]

I have gone through the below link and strange none for the solution for this. [MS Project file error](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-project/ms-project-2013-cannot-open-mpp-files-stored-in/059258a9-4854-4dd8-a4b8-ceacacb3973e?auth=1)

Answer (score 0):

Check if the path of the file is too long.

Besides, try opening the same file from the SharePoint Online in other client machines to see if it happens.